# WCF Message security

Tags: wcf, message, ws-security

I have a WCF service and Server certificate and Windows form or WPF client.

Does it necessary to export the private key to Client. If so why?. I thought we should only export public key to out side world. Please clarify me.

Answer (score 0):

You Should not need to publish the private key.  Are you using SSL for the connection.  If you so will need to set the bindings for Transport Level Security, and that should be it.  A client should be able to communicate with the server without needing to do very much fiddling around.

Comment: thanks for prompt response, let me tell you clearly. I have a WCF service and N number of WPF client. user can download WPF( Win Form)client from ClickOnce app. now i want to secure communication with Message level. whatt are the steps to active this. how handshake will happen in this case.

Comment: I have never needed to do that but I found a pretty good article on how to do it in a Dev environment.  I'm assuming that you would needed a Trusted Cert from an authority like Verisign, Etc.

http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Create%20and%20Install%20Temporary%20Certificates%20in%20WCF%20for%20Message%20Security%20During%20Development&referringTitle=How%20Tos&ProjectName=wcfsecurity